# How do I get a sprites position in pygame python (python wrapper for sdl)

Tags: python, pygame

I'm new to pygame and programming but I have a lot of networking expieriance (sorry I'm 9) because I've been researching how minecraft servers work and made one (when I was 8) so I've made it connect up but I've got to get the player pos to make sure it's within the right amount of pixels if it is it will send the player pos to the server and that will send to all of them and do the check then if true it will display it on the screen all of that would be in a loop of course

Comment: Yes, you're a good boy but i don't see how your age is relevant to the question? (sorry for coming off as a grumpy old man (25)).. Secondly, can you show some code? how do you handle player positions? how do you do anything?

Comment: You shouldn't apologize for being 9! You have a good question and have already done your homework on it, so you're in good shape. But you should show how you're handling players right now, so we know where to start. As @Torxed said.

Answer (score 0):

```
class player():
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

players = []
players.append(player(50, 50))
players.append(player(100, 100))
players.append(player(500, 500))

for i in range(0, len(players)):
    diff = players[i].x - player[i+1].x
    if (diff >= -50 and diff <= 50):
        print('player ' + str(i) + ' is in range with ' + str(i+1%len(players)))
```

Something as such? Rough mochup of how you can/should do it.
Pygame surely has some internals for it since it's a hughe API to make things simple and convenient but i usually make up my own functions and classes to figure out the mechanics before i go the easy route (another reason for it is to see if the convenient way gives me better processing power or not)

Comment: can i just get an ide right now ive been using the python ide it comes with ill report when its done

Comment: i gotta go to bed see ya tommorow

Comment: It all comes down to math really.
You have two positions, left-right (that's x), and up-down (that's y).
What you want to do is to take `x` from both players, divide them and see how big the difference is between them.
Not sure where you're from or the level of math you're at yet.. but say you have 5 apples, i got 3.. you want to know how faar in between we are..  `5-3=2`, meaning we're 2 apples away from eachother.. that's exactly how `x` and `y` is/should be calculated.

Comment: `player` would derive `pygame.sprite.Sprite` since he's using sprites. You also can use `sprite.Group()` to manage the instances.

Comment: Yes, normally you instantiate `player` with `pygame.sprite.Sprite` so that it inherits all the properties of `Sprite` but at the same time you'll get more options (creating your own functions to be used seamlessly along side with `Sprite`).